# WebAssembly in Uno platform not compiling due to an error on Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.dll

Tags: c#, mono, webassembly, uno-platform

So, I have been trying to compile a Wasm project with Uno.WebAssembly 3.0.17 but I get this error:

> Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void
> Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Converters.BoolToObjectConverter::.cctor()'
> in assembly: 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.dll' --->
> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve
> Uno.Diagnostics.Eventing.IEventProvider
> Uno.Diagnostics.Eventing.Tracing::Get(System.Guid)

Recently I had a similar issue with WebAssembly but was with the assembly **Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.dll** and the solution was to install the lastest version of the package **Uno.Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed** and the project resolved that problem, but this time i have no idea what package should I install to solve this problem. Any help?

[Here is a snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FOJQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BoolToObjectConverter` class is coming from the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/communitytoolkit/).

The Uno-compatible version is located in the [Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI). The NuGet packages for other WCT components are similarly named with a `Uno.*` prefix. If you install the latest. Uno.* versions in your WebAssembly head of all the WCT packages that are in your UWP head, it should work.

Comment: Thanks!!! It indeed solved the problem, I was using some UI extensions in my original project and now with that package, I can compile my project. The only thing was that this package is only available on the prerelease channel so when I tryied to look it up it was not visible but was as simple as check that option and installed it.

Comment: Is that still the case with the current version of Uno?